# Find search results using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the result of a search on any page, for example, amazon or ebay.
The results always have the form like this:

**1-50 of 3000 Results**

**1-30 of 3.999 Results**

**632,090 results found for laptop**

What I want is to get the number before the word "results". To do this I would create a regular expression like:

```
                             (any expression) number results
```

How can do this in JavaScript?

Comment: "the number to results to a search" - Are you talking about 3,999 in your example? If you specify which language your using, you will get more useful answers.

Comment: Are you sure these are the only two possible inputs? What about your expected output? Lastly what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match = subject.match(/\b\d+([.,]\d+)*\b(?=\s+results)/i);
if (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group n: match[n]
}
```

**Explanation :**

```
    // \b\d+([.,]\d+)*\b(?=\s+results)
// 
// Options: case insensitive
// 
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
// Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([.,]\d+)*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//    Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*»
//    Match a single character present in the list “.,” «[.,]»
//    Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
// Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\s+results)»
//    Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.) «\s+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//    Match the characters “results” literally «results»
```

Comment: Close but `/\b\d+([.,]\d+)?\b(?=\s+results)/i` won't match: `"1,234,567 results"` which has _more than one comma_. The problem is with: `([.,]\d+)?` which allows only one optional comma.

Comment: @ridgerunner Good point, I always work with the sample input of the OP. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your programming language, but if you only want the total number of results as a string

```
/ (\d+(?:,\d{3})*) Results/
```

will work in some languages.

For javascript:

```
var string = "1-50 of 3000 or 1 - 16 of 3,999 Results";
var pattern = /.*?([^ ]+) [rR]esults.*?/
var match = pattern.exec(string);
alert(match[0]);
```

Prints `3,999`, assuming that's what you want. Your question is a bit vague.

**EDIT:** Modified to work for "632,090 results found for laptop".

Comment: If the answer works, click the arrow icon on the upper left corner of the answer to 'accept' it.